E/flutter (21274): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Stack Overflow
When ever i run the aync function in my project it gaves me the error.
i first call the Future async function in the widget function and then call it in the widget. i an facing error still in this project. i am using the riverpod and make the function in the state notifier class.
THere is no recursive calls in it but still it happens.
